# Expecting types not the same as type definitions

Tags: haskell, types

I'm attempting to do problem 9 of Project Euler right now, but Haskell won't stop yelling at me about types not matching up. The thing is, ghci is telling me it is expecting types different than those given in the function type definitions.

Here is the code:

```
solvePyth :: Int -> Int -> Float
solvePyth x y
    |valid = x * y * z
    |otherwise = if y < x then solvePyth x (y + 1) else solvePyth (x + 1) 1
    where z = sqrt $ fromIntegral $ x^2 + y^2
          valid = (x^2 + y^2 == z^2) && (x + y + z == 1000)
```

and here are the errors I am getting:

```
Prelude> :l debug
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( debug.hs, interpreted )

debug.hs:3:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `Float' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `x * y'

debug.hs:3:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `Float' with actual type `Int'
    In the second argument of `(*)', namely `y'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `x * y'

debug.hs:6:33:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Float'
    In the first argument of `(^)', namely `z'
    In the second argument of `(==)', namely `z ^ 2'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What I don't understand is why `(*)` and `(^)` are expecting Floats and Ints, when checking their typing in ghci with `:t` shows their arguements only need to be considered Nums.

Comment: The type of `*` for example is `Num a => a -> a -> a` - you are correct that it accepts any instance of `Num`, however, it only accepts one type at a time, and returns the same type. The expression `x * y * z` has type `Int`, or it is not well typed, because you declared `x` to have type `Int`. However, you are returning a float. Simply put another `fromIntegral $ x * y * z`.

Comment: you also need to `round` the `z` equation, then you can set the result type to `Int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to fix the typing issue:

```
solvePyth :: Int -> Int -> Float
solvePyth x' y'
  | valid = x * y * z
  | otherwise = if y' < x' then solvePyth x' (y' + 1) else solvePyth (x' + 1) 1
  where z = sqrt (x^2 + y^2)
        (x, y) = (fromIntegral x', fromIntegral y')
        valid = (x^2 + y^2 == z^2) && (x + y + z == 1000)
```

`(*)` and `(^)` will work on arguments that are installed into `Num` class in general, but what is important is that the type have to be the same. Here is the type definition for `(*)`:

```
λ> :t (*)
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

but notice that `a` has to be the same type, so if you partially apply `Int` to it:

```
λ> :t (* (4 :: Int))
(* (4 :: Int)) :: Int -> Int
```

it expects the second argument and output to be an `Int` as well.

On the other hand type of `(^)`:

```
λ> :t (^)
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
```

works on two arguments of possibly different types, so if we partially apply an `Int` it will produce an `Int`, but the second argument can still be an arbitrary `Integral`:

```
λ> :t ((4 :: Int) ^)
((4 :: Int) ^) :: Integral b => b -> Int
```

Basically whenever you see `a -> a -> a`, it means that the type variable `a` eventually has to be of the same type, thats why you cannot mix `Int` and `Float` with `(*)`, despite that they are both installed into `Num`.